# How is a "wipe effect" intellectually accomplished, animated DIRECTIONAL fade-in from left to right

Tags: transparency, animation

I don't understand what a "wipe effect" or DIRECTIONAL fade in is "intellectually."  To provide some context, here is my graphics environment:

Layer 3: if needed, I can use too  (please note the runtime graphics environment only allows "simple addition" of the layers, that's all.  I use GIMP to make images, the open source similar program to photoshop, but I don't care the tool, I'm tring to understand it intellectually).

Layer 2: this will be a smaller PNG image I want to do a "wipe effect" or DIRECTIONAL fade in, e.g. from left to right, over the full background below.

Layer 1:  this will be whatever full background image I want.

This environment (the canvas in html) allows adjusting the opacity (or alpha) value of the entire layer, and I have the code to do this over time (that's easy).  My problem is, I don't understand "intellectually" what I need to do, to give the appearance of something (a png) image fading in "left to right".

E.g. if I were to create a gradiated black to alpha layer 3, I can do that too, but I think unless I make it exactly match the outline of the graphic I'm seeking to fade in, it will equally "disturb" the background, right?  So ... how is this done "intellectually", please?  Do I even need 3 layers, or is 2 fine?

Comment: Hi Ray, where are you making this document? Could you add the application tag please.

Comment: So, I use gimp to produce graphics, and the html canvas with javascript to do the animation.  Thanks I updated the question, but since I'm looking just for the intellectual "how to", I don't want to put these tags, unless needed.  Meaning, the tool to do it, shouldn't matter ??

Comment: Yes, but how is that used, to make something look, like it is being faded IN, FROM LEFT TO RIGHT  (or top to bottom, etc).

Comment: have you tried searching for the terms in your question? directional fade / wipe effect, fade animation? It seems your question is more about code implementation

Comment: No, it's intellectual.  I don't understand in graphics, what is going on, to do this.

Comment: So do you want to know how to create a gradient wipe with graphics, or learn how does the computer/code do? What do you mean "to understand intellectually"? Also please don't ask multiple questions in one.

Comment: @Luciano My understanding is the OP wants to understand how it works in theory (software agnostic if you prefer...).

Comment: @Ray I'm not proficient enough in canvas to write a proper answer, but have you tried [tweaking this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686738/css-fade-left-to-right) with 2 layers...where #1 is your empty background and #2 is the same background including the graphics you want to add?

Comment: Thanks @Emilie for trying to assist, and helping Luciano "get it."  So, I don't want to use this jquery tool, BUT, it would be interesting, to know how they are doing that, CONCEPTUALLY.  What does one need to do, conceptually, to accomplish this?  Then one can "write the code."  And my "first approach" isn't to dive into their code when I don't understand the overall "goal", hence my question here.

Comment: You asked "is it possible to produce a gradient, in a tool like GIMP, that only affects the alpha channel, and does NOT introduce a color?" - the answer to that is yes. It's called [a layer mask](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/). You can use a gradient as a layer mask in GIMP.

Comment: @BillyKerr, can this be saved out to a (png) file, or only used as a layer mask?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but you can export anything you want as a PNG.

Answer (score 1):

To do a directional fade in, put the image you want to be revealed at the bottom layer. Put the image visible at first above it. Then put the gradient or other mask on top.

As the gradient or mask moves across the page, cut the visible image when it's covered by the gradient. This will then reveal the bottom (new) image.

If you want to do this without a top level mask or gradient, simply do the cutting.